# Are there any health concerns around treated wood?

Tags: safety, pressure-treated

Last weekend I received a pallet of freshly pressure treated (still wet) green Wolmanit feather-edge cladding.

I have started to apply it to various buildings.

Obviously I am handling it with bare hands, there's wood dust from sawing etc.

Is there anything in this treatment that is likely to be a health concern?